# Wifi:still connected but no throughput

Tags: wireless, internet, acer, connection, 14.04

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer-laptop. Wifi is working, but after a couple of minutes there is no throughput, no up- nor download, although I am still connnected. As soon as I disconnect and reconnect, it works for a couple of minutes. Any ideas?

Comment: Same thing happens on my Acer Aspire V5. I'm suspecting about WLAN driver, I'll try to use an USB WLAN adaptor to be sure.

Comment: thanks! I also use an Acer Aspire V5. I am curious if it works with the stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gerald, I think I've solved it. Sorry for my delay, but I tried many things. After kernel update, it seems there is no freeze in transmission. It's also not related to power settings of wlan card (Atheros AR9462). Here is a simple guide for kernel update:

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-14-1-in-linux.html

I've upgraded to latest stable 3.14.1. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Great job! I tried it - seems like, it works. Thanks a lot!!!